# How to pass both props and a component as parameters of a functional component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, higher-order-components

I'm trying to create a modal component that can display several different form components depending on which is passed to it, so I need to pass the child component as an argument, and I've got the correct syntax to do that, but I can't figure out the syntax for passing both props from the modal's parent *and* the child component as parameters. I can get either to work individually, but not together.

```
import React from 'react';
import useToggle from './hooks/useToggle';

function Modal(props, {children}) {
    const [hidden, toggleHidden] = useToggle(props.hidden);
return (
    <div style={{
        position: 'fixed',
        textAlign: 'center',
        width: '100%',
        height: '100vh',
        display: `${hidden ? 'none' : 'flex'}`,
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .90)',
        zIndex: 1000
    }}>
        <div style={{
            width: '40%',
            height: '80%',
            border: '1px solid black',
        }}>
            <div style={{display: 'flex', width: '100%', height: '5%', justifyContent: 'end'}}>
                <button onClick={toggleHidden}>Close</button>                    
            </div>
            <div style={{zIndex: 1500, width: '50%', height: '50%', backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>
                {children}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
)
}

export default Modal;
```

The code above doesn't work, but if I change the first line to:

```
function Modal({children}) {
```

then I get the functionality of passing a child component, and if I change it to

```
function Modal(props) {
```

I'm able to pass the props down.

If both can be passed as arguments to the same functional component what is the correct syntax? And if not what is the standard workaround? I've been using props to toggle the display of the modal but I'm wondering if there's a better way if I can't pass both.

Thanks!

Comment: You can either just use `function(props) {...}` and then reference children as `props.children` or you can do sometihng like `function({ children, ...props }) {...}`. I haven't really seen the latter since `children` is one of the props, so I'd probably go with the former.

Comment: That worked, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because the `children` property is a child property of "props". What you can do is use `...rest` for the rest of the props. Like this

```js
function Modal(props, {children})
```

to

```js
function Modal({children, ...rest})
```